# How to Fill Form with Data in DJango without Update

Tags: django, forms, view

New to Django here. I have a link to a form in DJango. I use the CreateView to have the user enter the initial information. It all works great and the data is accurately saved to the database. My issue is this: I would like that same link to open the form (it's a one-to-one relationship) with the filled data so the user can see what they have previously entered and correct, edit or update as needed. The form currfently opens as a blank form so if the user has entered that information previously they are unable to see it. I cave researched get_or_create and update_or_create as well as a number of other topics, but can't seem to figure this out. This needs to be a user-friendly experience so multiple entires or clicking multiple buttons to access the data is not an option. How best can I implement this?

Comment: Show your efforts with some code instead of direct asking because you will be get negative response. see further stackoverflow guidelines. thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Don you can checkout [django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/), I think this will help in this situation. And you can use a single FormView for all your needs by overriding its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Django Sessions. It’s a simple way of saving session data and passing the data to future requests. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/. I. In your form view you cloud save the session data you want to pass to your next form. In your next form, you could use the session data as default values. I’ve done something similar in the past.